# Dynamically loaded .html page doesn't use cache for JS files

Tags: jquery, html, caching

The situation is this:

I have a page that loads sub-pages using Jquery.load():

```
loadMainContent: function(url, success)
{
    $("#app-main").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error")
        {
            /* @todo Show loading error page */
            console.log("Error message");
        }
        else
        {
            if (typeof success == "function")
            {
                success();
            }
        }
    });
    app.getSession();
}
```

The problem is: in loaded .html files, I include some '.js' files, that should be cached, but it's not beeing cached.

My google chrome console shows:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/travel/list". jquery.min.js:4 (The sub-page that i loaded)
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/js/bloodhound.js?_=1395932898636". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/js/core/typeahead.js?_=1395932898637". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/js/app-travel.js?_=1395932898638". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/js/moment.js?_=1395932898639". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/js/langs.js?_=1395932898640". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?_=1395932898641". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/ajax/query/session". jquery.min.js:4
XHR finished loading: "http://www.cdttravel.cashmate.com.br/ajax/travel/form/init". jquery.min.js:4
```

Note that all .js files are followed by a ?_=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx random number that is preventing them from beeing cached.

But I WANT the files cached in user browser. How do I remove this random query in the URL?
Apparently they are generated by Jquery, but not sure about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({'cache':true});
```

By default jQuery makes sure that requests to js files are never cached. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')

Comment: But using this solution, it may cache JSONs that I dont want to, right? Is there any way to enable cache just for script?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use `$.ajax` function instead of `$.load` to set cache settings on the per request basis.